# How to logout Facebook in App

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, ipad

I have an iPhone app which uses the  facebook sdk.
I should include a logout(that clears previous user total information) button to sign out the current user from my app.
How can i logout in my app?
Is there any way to do that.
I dont know how to do this,help me

Comment: Try this:     [FBSession.activeSession close];

Comment: Are you using iOS 6 (native FB) or ios 5 and lower ?

Comment: you will need to log-out from safari.

Comment: from safari becoz when i click on login with facebook in my app directly am getting my account

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD its not working

Comment: are you use Facebook SDK 3.1?

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD yes sdk 3.1

Comment: from safari is not working?? or what??

Comment: after login wit facebook i will get in to my app and there i have to logout fb(since after loading into app cannot load safari again)

Answer (score 0):

The session is retained in because the cookies of facebook is already present in your phone. You have to clear the cookies too.

Try this code. You can put it in the logout function you are using.

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSArray* facebookCookies = [cookies cookiesForURL:
                              [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://login.facebook.com"]];

for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in facebookCookies) {
  [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

**Note:** You also need to remove all the informations such us facebook token, user details from where ever you have saved in. May be you used `NSUserDefaults` or a db. You have to clear that also.

Comment: After running above code go back to safari and reload facebook.

Comment: i have my facebook after reloading

Answer (score 0):

Try below One

```
-(void) logoutFromFacebook: (id) logoutDelegate
 {

fbServiceRequestingobj = logoutDelegate;
[facebook logout:self];
 }
```

Comment: can u tell me what is "fbServiceRequestingobj" and "facebook"

Comment: Facebook *facebook;
    id fbServiceRequestingobj;   i declared both in .h file

Answer (score 0):

use this code

> if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
>       [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation]; }